# How to merge and transform data in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, string-aggregation

A sql query yields data that looks like this:

| name | quality | magnitude |
| --- | --- | --- |
| john | kindness | 7 |
| john | greed | 2 |
| jane | kindess | 3 |
| jane | greed | 7 |
| john | temper | 9 |
| jane | temper | 4 |

I am wondering if there is a way to transform it into data that looks like this using SQL:

| name | personality |
| --- | --- |
| john | kindess:7, greed:2, temper:9 |
| jane | kindess: 3, greed: 7, temper: 4 |

If yes:

1. How do it do it?
2. Is this an optimal/good idea?

I am on Postgres 9+

Comment: All of the Postgres 9.x versions are end-of-life and no longer maintained. You should plan an upgrade to a supported version as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `string_agg()` for this

```
select name, 
       string_agg(concat(quality, ':', magnitude), ', ') as personality
from the_table
group by name;
```

With a more up-to-date Postgres version, I would probably aggregate this into a JSON value which is easier to work with when you need to process the result:

```
select name, 
       jsonb_object_agg(quality, magnitude) as personality
from the_table
group by name;
```

That would return:

```
name | personality                             
-----+-----------------------------------------
john | {"greed": 2, "temper": 9, "kindness": 7}
jane | {"greed": 7, "temper": 4, "kindess": 3}
```

Comment: Or possibly an array? Anything's better than a string!

Comment: @Vérace: I'd say an array isn't really suited for a list of key/value pairs. JSON is the natural choice for that (or hstore for outdated Postgres versions)